# Serialising a String using Kryo giving wrong output

Tags: java, arrays, serialization, byte, kryo

I am attempting to use [Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) to serialise and deserialise objects. This is working for complex types (like `Optional` and `Option`) but not simpler types like `String`. The issue looks to be on the serialisation side (deserialisation looks to be working fine). The serialisation code looks like:

```java
private String serialize(T input) {
  Output output = new Output(2, -1);
  kryo.writeObjectOrNull(output, input, type);
  output.close();
  final var bytes = output.toBytes();
  return new String(bytes);
}
```

where `type` is `Class<T>` (e.g. if `T` is `String` then `type` would be `String.class`). If I compare `input.getBytes()` to `bytes` I can see that all of the bytes in the `byte[]` are correct other than the last byte. This would result in an input of something like `test144` and a serialised output of `test14�`.

I stepped through the code using an example of type `String` and can see that the output value is actually correct until [this](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo/blob/7b640984413c5e2bbed23ef3e5eb20204f79f94e/src/com/esotericsoftware/kryo/io/Output.java#L668) line is executed (looks to be doing some sort of Bitwise OR for whatever reason).

Unsure if this is something I am doing wrong or a bug in the library.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Found the same problem as well - last byte is different. This is causing trouble with using Redis' binary commands